# Conditional Class Attribute

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am busy developing a mobile app in Ionic v4 using Angular as my front end. I am currently using `animate.css` to animate some of the transitions. I would like one div to fade out and the other fade in once data has been loaded on the backend.

So I have gotten the switching part right, using an `*ngIf` on each of the div's to check when the data has been pulled through. Using `animate.css` I can get the second div to fade in by applying `animated fadeIn` to the class attribute of the div.

So the only part left is to fade out the first div, now I have tried conditionally setting the classes for the div using: `[ngClass]="(information != null) ? 'animated fadeOut' : ''"` but it would seem to me that this only gets evaluated once when the view renders and never again, unlike `*ngIf`.

Does anyone know a way I can conditionally apply a class on a div when the evaluated expression is true, that will be checked throughout the lifecycle of the view such as `*ngIf`?

Comment: The `ngClass` expression should be evaluated on every change detection cycle.

Comment: @ConnorsFan is right, ngClass evaluates on every change detection cycle. Check if the value of your variable used in ngClass expression changes or not.

Comment: See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6bxnu) for a demo.